# Limitations of conjure-up on AWS

Tags: juju, amazon-ec2

I saw an initial set up video of conjure-up on AWS. Here is the video URL.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=at3ZNjV3ZtI

I know that kubernetes can do pod scaling per https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/

How does conjure-up manage to scale in/out AWS EC2 instances?
I saw that juju does this. https://docs.jujucharms.com/2.5/en/charms-scaling
Can you please confirm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The CDK bundle does not add kubernetes-worker nodes on high workloads. AFAIK Conjure-up also does not provide this. Juju allows you to scale the number of master / worker nodes manually via `juju add-unit`.

If you really want autoscaling feature you can look at non canonical solutions such as the following [bundle](https://jujucharms.com/u/elastisys/autoscaled-kubernetes/bundle/0).

Pod scaling works on the Kubernetes level and does not require node auto scaling.